# Linker command failed to execute code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

when i compile code then Linker command failed to execute code 1 (use -v to see invocation) error is occurred but actually i don't know where i made mistakes.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is duplicate file in Your Project >> Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources.

Remove Duplicate files from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to your project setting page
2. Select your project (left side)
3. Click the "Build Settings" tab
4. Search "Bitcode"
5. Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No"